# How to list unversioned directory in svn?

Tags: linux, unix, svn

I have a few unversioned directories in my local copy on my Linux. The svn status doesn't list the unversioned directories. The command `svn status| grep ^?` only lists unversioned files in versioned directories. What's the command to list unversioned directories and the files in it?

Comment: Which svn version are you using? Typically `svn status` lists only unversioned directories but not the files in them.

Answer (score 1):

### The idea

`svn add` command will add unversioned files and folders and list them as well. We do want to list them, but we do not want to add them. So, we can run `svn rm --keep-local` after that to revert adding (and **avoid discarding local modifications**).

### Details

Run:

```
svn add * --force
```

which will list all unversioned objects in your working copy (including those with `svn:ignore` property). But, this will also mark for adding all these objects.

Why do you need `--force` option is [described in SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html):

> Normally, the command svn add * will skip over any directories that
>   are already under version control. Sometimes, however, you may want to
>   add every unversioned object in your working copy, including those
>   hiding deeper. Passing the --force option makes svn add recurse into
>   versioned directories

Then, just revert those addings and keep local modifications (note the trailing dot):

```
svn rm --keep-local .
```

Why do you need `--keep-local` option is [described in SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html):

> Use the --keep-local option to override the default svn delete
>   behavior of also removing the target file that was scheduled for
>   versioned deletion. This is helpful when you realize that you've
>   accidentally committed the addition of a file that you need to keep
>   around in your working copy, but which shouldn't have been added to
>   version control.

This obviously has side effect of removing all addings, including those that are intentional.

After this, you should have a list of unversioned files and folders, with untouched local copy.